# How to contact an Ubuntuforum administrator?

Tags: ubuntu-forums

I would like to contact a forum administrator and I don't want to log to my Ubuntu One account because I'm closing it.

So I can't log to my forum account and I'd like to close it too.

So, what can I do? :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Join #ubuntuforums on IRC (irc.freenode.net), an admin might be able to help if they're on..  Ask Ubuntu can't really help much with the forums.

Answer (score 9):

**This edit from a Forum Council member.**

In order the preferred methods for contacting the Forum Council are

1. Via the [Resolution Centre](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=123) where possible
2. Via the Forum council mailing list
   ubuntu-forums-council@lists.ubuntu.com
3. Via the #ubuntuforums channel on Freenode (if we are about)
4. Via an Admin's launchpad page

You can find all Ubuntu Forums administrators in Launchpad. The page is [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-forum-members/+members#active)

You can contact them via Launchpad directly, click the username and "contact this user", but this requires a login in Launchpad. 
Additionally, as most of them are Ubuntu Members (I think this is a prerequisite) you can contact them by e-mail through the Ubuntu Members alias. The e-mail always is the username in launchpad (what is appears in browser's address bar) and @ubuntu.com (this is not a secret). This e-mail address is a forwarding alias to another address that the member opted when became Ubuntu Member.

Last but not least, the **IRC** is a great place on getting touch with lot of people. Connect in Freenode Server, the channel is **#ubuntuforums** .  Drop your request there and hopefully someone who is an administrator will answer to you.

All above are not Official contact ways, are just my solution to your query. I mean if you use something of above and you'll not receive any answer, this is not a fault of UF administrators, or Canonical.

Answer (score 6):

Please send an email to the forums council :

ubuntu-forums-council@lists.ubuntu.com

Be sure to include identifying information (name of the ubuntu  forums account, email associated with the account, Lanuchpad info).

Comment: This answer is the one most likely to get a quick response - all of the FC monitor this list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Single sign-on support form**](https://forms.canonical.com/sso-support/) and complain about you want. First, select **Other** for **I am looking for support with ...** field.

Also, you can see: [Can I cancel/delete my SSO account?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO/FAQs/Delete_SSO_Account)

> SSO accounts must be deleted manually. To do this, [send email to ISD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ISD) (*isd-support@canonical.com*) from the address used for your SSO account, with a subject line like "delete SSO account - myemail@example.com". Please specify the account email in your message, along with the reason you would like to get rid of the account and acknowledgement that you don't mind losing access to everything attached to the account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've contacted the SSO team and everything is fine for the other account. I'm waiting for the answer of the Canonical  team about contacting an admin.

Comment: @Kuba If the answer was useful, you should accept it.

Comment: This answer while generically useful to contact SSO - it will not help disable a UbuntuForums account, just a fyi.

Comment: To contact the council see : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ForumCouncil , specifically the mailing list. I gave you the link in my answer above.