# IP address banned from ubuntuforums?

Tags: ubuntu-forums

I am not a very experienced Ubuntu user, so I have to look up some information on the internet. Most of the links lead to http://ubuntuforums.org. But each time I try to open a page on this site, it says "Sorry. The administrator has banned your IP address. To contact the administrator click here". That seems strange, because it is the first time I have ever been on ubuntuforums.org.

The worst thing is: when I click on the word "here" to contact the administrator, it says "The administrator may have required you to register before you can view this page." I tried logging in with SSO as it says, but when I open the login page, the message about my ban appears again.

I tried to contact the ForumCouncil from their page, but it gives me the same error => I can't open it

Is there any way to find out the reason why my IP was banned?
Thank you.

Comment: What about http://ubuntuforums.org instead of http://ubuntuforums.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They've undoubtedly banned it because somebody on the other end of it was spamming or performing other undesirable behaviour. You've got two choices:

- Get a new IP. If you're on a dynamic allocation (which you probably are) rebooting the router might get you a fresh one.
- Talk to the [Forums Community Council](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ForumCouncil), explain the situation and request they unblock the IP.

We're not the same people here so can't help you directly.

Comment: Unfortunately I previously hosted game servers, so I have a static IP address...

Comment: Contacting the ForumCouncil didn't work either, since I just can't open the page - it gives me the same error... Thank you anyway, but that didn't solve my problem : (

Comment: @complover116 They have an email address. I'd suggest using it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327095/how-to-contact-an-ubuntuforum-administrator?rq=1

Comment: @Oli Thank you! I didn't see it for some reason